# angularjs is not loading when using express

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js, express

when I open index.html file in browser it work fine but when I run it on local server in express it doesn't work.

server.js

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('App is running on port 3000');
});
```

app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$filter', '$http', function($scope, $filter, $http) {
    $scope.handle = '';
    enter code here

}]);
```

index.html

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title>Angularjs</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="mainController">
        <div>
            <input type="text" ng-model="handle">
        </div>
        <br/>
        <h1>Hello {{ handle }}</h1>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50193292/6804958) answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need another route to server the controller file (`app.js`) from server.

Something like

```
app.get('/app.js', (req, res) => {
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/app.js');
});
```

What's wrong with you'r code is , when you sever the `index.html` file from server and when it is rendered in browser, browser now send a request to load the `app.js` file (which is your controller) and you don't respond to that request. That'w why your app does not work.

Ps. if you open your network tab and check for `404` response code. You'll see that for `app.js` file.

Comment: I didn't check the network tab which give 404 response code for app.js file.